# When android use util.map, data persistence

Tags: java, android, dictionary, data-storage

I'm begginer in android.

When I studied the Android App source for my school project, I have some questions.

In source code, use the Map Class(Java.util.Map) for save some data.
like this...

```
Map<String, Connection> connections = Connections.getInstance(this).getConnections();
```

And in application run, the data that saved Map type in the past are reuse when the application is restart.

If the data saved once, anytime can use that until removed?

When application is closed, the data is not removed?

Thanks.

Comment: From what i have under stand you want to store data...which should remain when app is restart right ? Then use shared preference or database ....you can find more info here ...
[link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: Thnks @shreyashmashru ! but, I want to know that, not use database or shared Preferences, when just save Map type, that data is remain after the app close?

Comment: Save Map Type means adding to map right ? Then no data will not remain after app close.

Comment: Ah... Ok, I see. The app reuse data after restart means data saved another data-storage not util.Map? Thanks for your reply!